# Tag Cleanup: Tags to be Merged

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Following up on [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180/meta-tag-debate-microchip-and-pic-atmel-and-avr) discussion about tags and [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/what-meta-tags-on-er-should-be-axed) discussion about tags to be deleted, I am setting up this question as a list of tags that should be merged. Users can add tags to be merged to the question, and Admins can remove them after they have been merged, or decided to be kept.

**Reasons for merging a tag:**

- The tag is too specific, or focuses on a small subset of the problem
- Other questions would not be able to use it.
- The tag is a close match for another tag (e.g. desolder, desoldering, de-solder)

**Tags to be merged:**

```
0402, 0603, 0805, surfacemount, msop -> smd
ccsv4 -> ccs
7805, 78xx -> voltage-regulator
```

Comment: 0402, 0603, 0805, msop, smd -> surfacemount is better, I think.  And the synonym system is better than merging tags.

Comment: @endolith agreed

Comment: @endolith, I can merge tags to allow a currently less used tag to become the master tag when you add a synonym. I explained this to @W5VO. He does not have 1500 rep, so he cannot do synonyms yet.

Comment: @endolith, you also made a synonym of surfacemount to smd. I have cleaned it up, they all go to surface-mount now.

Comment: Yeah, smd was more common so I didn't have a choice.

Comment: @endolith, I remembered!

Comment: Hi. I haven't received any reaction to my request, does this mean that it's not valid or it was just not noticed? I'm not sure if I should have created a question instead of posting an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

- [microsd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsd)
- [sd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd)

Should all be the same ([sd] or [secure-digital]...).  Maybe add [mini-sd], [minisd], [micro-sd] or whatever as synonyms for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

[Debugging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging) and [Debug](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debug) should probably be merged/synonyms.

Question is, does an ICD fit into these at all?

Comment: I just came here to post about the same ones. To me, they pertain only to software or debuggers specifically, not general hardware problems, as in [this post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8128/need-help-debugging-my-project-fuses-popping-like-crazy-but-i-cant-find-the-re). What about making `[Debugging]` and `[Debug]` synonyms, and using `[Debugger]` separately? (Also making `[In-Circuit-Debugger]`, `[In-Circuit-Debugging]`, and `[ICD]` synonyms; maybe merging `[JTAG]` in a few months if it is relatively unused.)

Comment: I feel that [debug] -> [debugging], and that should be a software/programming task. I would like to make [troubleshooting] refer to strictly hardware issues. I think that distinction between hardware and software is significant for the techniques used.

Comment: @Kortuk feels [`debug`](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debug) & [`debugging`](http://goo.gl/YO2Qb) apply to hardware as well as software. Maybe we can leave them separate from [`troubleshooting`](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) for the time being, then see how the community uses them to choose the successor. I think [`debugwire`](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugwire) can be made a synonym of [`debugger`](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugger); they are both used.

Answer (score 3):

[`I2C`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/i2c/info) and [`TWI`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/twi/info) should be merged, they are the same thing with a different non patented name

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Derivative_technologies

> TWI (Two Wire Interface) or TWSI (Two-Wire Serial Interface) is essentially the same bus implemented on various system-on-chip processors from Atmel and other vendors.[9] Vendors use the name TWI, even though I²C is not a registered trademark. Trademark protection only exists for the respective logo (See upper right corner) and patents on I²C have now lapsed.

Answer (score 2):

- [Level](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/level)
- [Shifter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shifter)
- [bidirectional](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bidirectional)
- [voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage)

Level-Shifter Voltage-Shifter seem like the same.

Bidirectional seems rather vague.

Comment: `[bidirectional]` could be deleted, IMO. I agree on the shifting. `[voltage]` may have a place by itself, though. What do you think?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/546/voltage-level-shifter That question used voltage where it should be voltage-shifter.

Answer (score 2):

[tqfp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qfp) and [qfp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqfp) should probably be merged/synonymed/deleted. QFP has no questions, tqfp has three.  Should they be merged into [surface-mount]?  It's a hard call, some packages (like DIP or BGA) are specific enough that they deserve their own tag, others not so much (0402/0603/0805 etc.  Sadly, [IEC-60115-8] just doesn't quite roll off the tongue).

Also, [[max]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max) [[msp]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msp) (2 tags) and [[msp430]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msp430) should get some attention. MAX/MSP apparently has something to do with Arduino programming, and some questions are being mistagged with combinations of these three.

Answer (score 2):

`capacitance`
`capacitive`
`capacitor`

either need merging or they need tag wikis to differentiate them

Comment: I think they should all fall under capacitor. Could a mod take a look at it?

Comment: I'm not sure they all should be combined.  Questions about parasitic capacitance shouldn't really be tagged capacitor?  I think of "capacitor" as a physical component, and "capacitance" as a property that lots of things have.

Answer (score 2):

[`can`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/can/info) (x64) and [`canbus`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/canbus/info) (x3) should be merged, they both refer to the same thing.

canbus should be a synonym of can

Comment: I have made the synonym

Answer (score 1):

## resolved

weird tag: [`Arduino-Shield`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-shield). I'm not sure what it really means, if anything. Can we just get rid of it? There are a zillion different shields.

Comment: Probably makes sense, especially given that most shields are totally unrelated apart from being Arduino compatible...so the question should be tagged as such anyways.  Maybe make it a synonym for [arduino]

Comment: @nickt, @tyblu, doe an arduino-mega to arduino synonym make sense also?

Comment: @Kortuk, I'm not sure. I haven't looked into the Arduino scene (it **is** a scene!). I believe the vast majority of them use the ATmega series, but I know the ["Netduino" uses an ARM](http://netduino.com/netduino/specs.htm). It seems like a "clone"; ie: not part of the Arduino company.

Comment: I am making the synonym as all questions with arduino-mega have arduino also.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new tag a few days ago: [`[programmable-logic]`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programmable-logic). I figured CPLDs and other PLDs, including PALs, would fit in this category, but not FPGAs due to frequency of use and fundamental IC differences. Since then [`[PAL]`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pal) and [`[CPLD]`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpld) tags have been made. **Do we merge, [*synonym*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/programmable-logic/synonyms), forget, or delete?**