# Is there a reason for [tag:texas-instruments]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a rationale for the [texas-instruments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas-instruments) tag?

I don't see how that's a sensible category for engineering questions – if you want to talk about something like [msp430](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msp430), there's a tag for that, and it really doesn't matter who produces the buck converter controller you have a question about, does it?

Didn't want to this "tag-cleanup" right away, because maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: Notice that most questions don't even mention "Texas Instruments", apart from the tags.

Comment: There is also a "st" tag, a "nxp" tag, a "renesas" tag, and you can probably go on... I don't have any strong feelings whether it makes sense or not, but we should probably apply the same rationale for all of those tags.

Comment: Also, for reference, here are related discussion about manufacturer tags: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6624/107479 and https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/180/107479

Comment: TI has such a broad product range that the tag has little meaning,  unlike the other companies mentioned in comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the sort of case where we should be able to ban a meaningless tag from *future* use, but where retroactively touching questions to remove it would create unjustified churn cluttering up the main page.

Comment: That would be pretty sensible.